# Data don't get selected from a table within Wordpress plugin

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am building a simple Wordpress plugin to handle some data. For a user, it returns data in JSON format; for an admin, it allows the data to be manipulated via admin panel expansion. And I have very simple data schema:

```
CREATE TABLE shops (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    area VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(256),
    tel VARCHAR(16),
    zip VARCHAR(12),
    website VARCHAR(128),
    email VARCHAR(128),
    UNIQUE KEY id (id)
);

CREATE TABLE ratings (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    shop INT(11) NOT NULL,
    rating INT(1),
    UNIQUE KEY id (id)
);
```

I want to select a list of shops, and put its average ratings next to each of them. The select query is

```
SELECT 
    shops.id AS id,
    shops.area AS area,
    shops.name AS name,
    shops.address AS address,
    shops.tel AS tel,
    shops.zip AS zip,
    shops.website AS website,
    shops.email AS email,
    AVG(ratings.rating) AS rating
FROM shops AS shops
LEFT JOIN ratings AS ratings
    ON shops.id = ratings.shop
GROUP BY shops.id;
```

So, I also want a user to insert some data. As WP Codex denotes, I should use `$wpdb->insert(...)` which I do, from a POST request query data:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert(
    'shops',
    array(
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'area' => $_POST['area'],
        'address' => $_POST['address'],
        'tel' => $_POST['tel'],
        'zip' => $_POST['zip'],
        'website' => $_POST['website'],
        'email' => $_POST['email']
    ),
    array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
);
```

Data gets inserted, by no data is being shown. I use such a construction:

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT 
        shops.id AS id,
        shops.area AS area,
        shops.name AS name,
        shops.address AS address,
        shops.tel AS tel,
        shops.zip AS zip,
        shops.website AS website,
        shops.email AS email,
        AVG(ratings.rating) AS rating
    FROM shops AS shops
    LEFT JOIN ratings AS ratings
        ON shops.id = ratings.shop
    GROUP BY shops.id;
");

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->id . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->area . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->name . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->address . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->tel . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->zip . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->website . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->email . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->rating . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="' . admin_url('admin.php?page=rnr_admin_upd&id=' . $row->id) . '">Update</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: @vidhu-nair found a typo. As, with typo fixed, data inserts well, I restated my question a little.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the format If string, the format will be `%s`
you have a typo in the format change it to  `array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')`

Comment: You are right, I should have looked a little more attentively. Now, the insert executes well. But select statement still returns 0 rows.

Comment: does var_dump($rows) return anything?

Comment: No, it doesn't, just like dataset is empty.

Comment: so there is no such rows, check your query